# Extract value as comma separated list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a list below and i want to get a list of value as comma-separated values:

```
[{"id":49},{"id":61},{"id":5},{"id":58}]
```

I tried pluck but it only returns single value. I want:

```
49,61,5,58
```

I can do it in many ways but i want to do it in laravel way.

Code:

```
   $locations = Location::select('id')->whereIn('id', function($query) use ($id)
            {
                $query->select('location_id')
                    ->from('users_locations')
                    ->whereRaw('user_id ='.$id);
            })->get();
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to get this collection. If it's a standard collection, pluck will definitely work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$t='[{"id":49},{"id":61},{"id":5},{"id":58}]' ;
$ARRAY=json_decode($t,true);
$ARRAY=array_column($ARRAY,'id')
$VALUE=implode(',',$ARRAY);
```

IT GIVE OUTPUT AS

[image]

With simple **json_decode()** ,**array_column()** and **implode()**

Comment: if your issue is solved the close your question by accepting my answer :)

Comment: Please add semi colon in this statement array_column($ARRAY,'id'); @BibhudattaSahoo

Comment: we need to wait for few mins to accept an answer. i was waiting for it.

Answer (score 16):

Using the collection class you can do this, since it's json you have to decode it first so it's an array, which you can convert to a `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

```
$data = json_decode('[{"id":49},{"id":61},{"id":5},{"id":58}]', true);
$csv_data = collect($data)->pluck('id')->implode(',');
```

If you want the array of values instead of the string, remove the `implode` call.

---

After seeing your code this should work just fine.

```
$csv_data = $locations->pluck('id')->implode(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a standard collection, you don't need to use `json_decode()`. Collection `pluck()` method will work:

```
$collection->pluck('id');
```

You can also use Eloquent's `pluck()` method instead of using `select()` and `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** use `json_decode` decode the json string into array

**2nd :** use array_column to get the `specific column` from `array`

**3rd :** use `implode` to break the `array` into `string` .

```
<?php

$array ='[{"id":49},{"id":61},{"id":5},{"id":58}]';

echo implode(',',array_column(json_decode($array,true),'id'));

?>
```

*I can do it in many ways but i want to do it in laravel way.* **That's why i deleted my answer while !!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$data_arr = json_decode('[{"id":49},{"id":61},{"id":5},{"id":58}]', true);
$resultarr = array();
foreach($data_arr as $data){
    $resultarr[] = $data['id'];
}
echo implode(',', $resultarr);
```